# MySql Query to select over a range of dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains:

```
line | date | metricName | metricValue
```

I want to 
`select where date > curDate() - 30 days`

-condition is that for each record

`where metricName = "foo" AND metricName != "bar"`(metric value has never been "bar").

Essentially in the entire span of time if the metricValue ever did = "Bar" i dont want to see the line.

Comment: What you have tried so far ??

Comment: It looks like @usermecart1923 has changed the meaning of your question (`metricValue` => `metricName`). Please clarify your post.

Answer (score 0):

This should exclude all of those lines from consideration. I hope `line` is a primary key. Or better yet, what is the table indexed on?

```
SELECT
  `line`
FROM
  `the_table`
WHERE
  `date` > NOW() - 'your interval' AND
  `metricName` = 'foo' AND
  `line` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `line` FROM `the_table` WHERE `metricName` = 'foo' AND `metricValue` = 'Bar'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  `line`
    FROM  `the_table`
    WHERE  `date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
      AND  `metricName` = 'foo'
      AND  NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  `the_table`
            WHERE  `metricName` = 'foo'
              AND  `metricValue` = 'Bar' 
      );
```

For performance you will need two composite indexes:

```
INDEX(metricName, date),
INDEX(metricName, metricValue)
```